# MS Web Deployment script errors and TeamCity

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity, web-deployment

So we make use of TeamCity as a CI server (v 7.1.1). And we use MS' own web deployment tool as a means of publishing to our servers (standard ASP.NET fare). However, I've noticed that the batch files that are generated by web deploy seem to play badly with TeamCity.

This is what appears in the build log:
http://dpaste.com/826346/

The script clearly says an error has happened. However, TC seems unable to detect this, as no red lights come on. Is there a (good) way to fix and detect this, so we don't get incorrect build runner status reports? TC is currently setup so that the deployment script is executed by a Command Line runner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it, change the IIS site AppPool to .net version 4.0 - Your error message says that the app expects 4.0 but web deployment tool is finding 2.0

To detect it, I think you can configure the Build Failure Condition, to fail a build when "an error message is logged by build runner".[image: fail a build when an error message is logged by build runner]

Comment: Checking that alone did not seem to change anything, however the nearby "Add build failure condition" has an option to scan the log for some exact text, which does work, at least for putting big read text on the overview page, which is what I mainly wanted ;-)